# Controller Undefined after Form Submit: Argument 'RegistrationController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I wrote some custom routing in my app configuration file to handle routing of all my html templates and controllers instead of having to specifically define the route for every single html and controller. I have a Registration.html and RegistrationController.js under my Modules/Account/ directory. My app can find the controller the first time I go to it and I can fill out the page and submit the form on the page. After I submit successfully, I get redirected to a success page. When I try to go back to the same registration html/controller the 2nd time, it can find my html template, but it can not find my controller anymore and i get the error "Argument 'RegistrationController' is not a function, got undefined". Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this?

Please note this error only happens after a form submit. If I leave the page and go back to it without doing a form submit, everything works fine.

App Config

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'ui-bootstrap', 'ui-grid'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: function (rp) { return 'Modules/Account/login.html'; },
        controllerUrl: 'Modules/Account/LoginController'
    }))
    .when("/:module/:page", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: function (rp) { return 'Modules/' + rp.module + '/' + rp.page + '.html'; },
        resolve: {
            load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
                var path = $location.path();
                var parsePath = path.split('/');
                var parentPath = parsePath[1];
                var controllerName = parsePath[2];

                var loadController = "Modules/" + parentPath + "/" + controllerName + "Controller";
                debugger;
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                require([loadController], function () {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }
    }))
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);

loadDirectives(app);
angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

return app;
});
```

RegistrationController

```
define(['app-config','accountService'], function (app) {
app.register.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$uibModal', 'accountService',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $uibModal, accountService) {
        $rootScope.applicationModule = "Account";

        $scope.registerUserSuccess = function (response, status) {
            debugger;
            $location.path("/Account/RegistrationSuccess");
        }

        $scope.registerUserFailure = function (response, status) {
            if (!response.ValidationErrors) {
                $scope.ErrorList = [];
                $scope.ErrorList.push("An error occurred. Please contact the system's administrator");
            }
            else {
                $scope.ErrorList = response.ValidationErrors;
            }
        }

        $scope.onSubmitClick = function (isValid) {
            if (isValid) {
                accountService.registerUser($scope.regModel, $scope.registerUserSuccess, $scope.registerUserFailure);
            }
        }

        $scope.onCancelClick = function () {
            $location.path("/Login");
        }
    }
]);
});
```

Comment: your question does not have RegistrationController code

Comment: I did not see the need to post it since there is nothing wrong with the RegistrationController. If I put a specific definition for the controller in my routerprovider, then it finds the controller every time and everything always works. My problem is that the custom routing I wrote above can't find my controller the 2nd time. It can only find it the first time I go to the controller.

Comment: No the problem is with your controller

Comment: I updated my question with the controller.

Comment: I'm using requireJS for lazy loading.

Comment: Maybe not relevant but in your template, is your form trying to do an actual POST or submit and bypassing your javascript submit code?

Comment: No. I do have a input button of type "submit" but its wrapped around an ng-form div which is tied to an ng-submit which calls a function in my RegistrationController that makes an http.post. After the ajax call is completed successfully, I do a redirect to a success page via $location.path()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't honed in on the answer yet, but I've noticed some refactoring that you should do that might get you closer to figuring out your problem ...

1. Stop using controllers. Use components, which were introduced in 1.5. These are superior in their reusability. They are more flexible in how you can use them and in what you can pass into them. The only controllers you should be using are the ones in components.
2. Stop using $scope or $rootScope for anything. Used named controllers. This is the default setting for a component.
3. Consider ui-router over angular-route. It's just a lot better.
4. What is loadDirectives(app) doing?
5. Put a log statement in your RegistrationContoller.js and just verify that it isn't being called more than once. If it thinks RegistrationController is undefined after previously being defined, it just feels like it's being defined more than once.
6. Is there anything fishy in accountService.registerUser? Is this function forwarding you to the success screen? That's kind of weird... seems to me that the accountService.registerUser should return a promise, and the onSubmitClick should resolve the promise and forward the user.
7. Try forwarding back to the RegistrationController at different points in the code, and try to narrow down the exact point that it becomes undefined. I think that you have some code running somewhere that you don't think you do.

Comment: You are correct. I had a duplicate RegistrationController. In terms of #6, I actually pass $scope.Error function from my controller to my accountService so that the accountService.registerUser.then() calls it and handles my loadmasking via $rootScope. Refactoring out the $scope and $rootScope would be a little difficult for me right now since I use it for my load masking on my saves and loading of html forms. Thanks agai nfor your help!